# Как изменить стиль EditText в AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-themes, android-alertdialog

Как изменить стиль EditText? Первая каритнка - то что есть сейчас, вторая - то, что мне нужно (цвет не имеет значения).

**dialog_input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/md_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/subj_name_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Hello, World!"
            android:hint="@string/subject_name_dialog_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="32" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `EditText` уберите отступ при старте (`paddingStart`), уменьшите отступ снизу (`paddingBottom`12dp по умолч. - отступ) и фон прозрачный нужно сделать (или белый).

```
<EditText
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    ....
```

Еще мне кажется что увеличен отступ сверху, нужно измерить и выставить (28dp по умолч. + отступ)

```
android:paddingTop="34dp"
```